# Is there an endofunctor of the category of sets that maps $\kappa$ to $\kappa^+$?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

For already some time I am slightly bothered by the following question about endofunctors of the category of sets: Is there an endofunctor of set which maps each infinite cardinal $\kappa$ to a set of size $\kappa^+$ (i.e., the first larger cardinality)?

It is clear that under GCH, an example of such a functor is the power set functor as $2^\kappa = \kappa^+$. But without this axiom, I don't know of any other example. Anyway, I was interested whether one can construct such functor without any additional set axioms. To rephrase the question once mo: **Is it always true under ZFC that there exists an endofunctor of the category of sets that maps $\kappa$ to a set of size $\kappa^+$?**

My master thesis advisor suggested that such functor might be found as a subfunctor of the powerset functor, but I never managed to make it work. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't the fact that the successor function $\kappa\mapsto\kappa^+$ is itself definable from $\sf ZF$ is enough to conclude there is such functor?

Comment: You still need to define the functor on morphisms which is definetely not easy.

Comment: Also what exactly do you mean by definable? Is it first order definable?

Comment: @Jakub Yes, it's clearly first-order definable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks, I am just little slow.

Comment: But you don't mention any condition for the functor, so you can just fix an element from each nonempty set (using choice, of course) and send all functions to the constant one, mapping everything to the picked element of the codomain.

Comment: @Berci: But global choice is not a theorem of ZFC. Not even global choice "from a parameter". Also, how does this definition preserves the identity and composition (together)?

Comment: Note that there is a "canonical" way to construct a set of size $|X|^+$ from a set $X$: take the set of isomorphism classes of well-orderings of subsets of $X$.  This construction is functorial with respect to bijections in an obvious way (which turns out to be rather trivial; every automorphism gets sent to the identity).  Unfortunately this cannot be extended to be functorial with respect to all functions.

Comment: Incidentally, it is not clear to me that even assuming GCH there is a functor which sends $\kappa$ to a set of size $\kappa^+$ for _all_ cardinals (including finite ones).

Comment: Anyways, it seems highly likely to me that the answer to your question is "no", but proving a negative answer would of course require some serious set theory since such a functor does exist in some models.

Comment: @EricWofsey I like the construction of $\kappa^+$, thanks for sharing. It's good to know that there is such a thing.

Comment: @EricWofsey About the extension to finite cardinals, I think there is one. The requirement for finite sets is very strong. If you want to map $n$ to $n+1$ you are forced to define it as $F(x) = x \cup \{*\}$ where $*$ is a new point. Anyway, thankfully I can use the point $*$ for my extension. Let us first define
$$
P_{\geq\kappa} X = \{ A \subseteq X : |A| \geq \kappa \} \cup \{*\}
$$
this extends to maps as $ P_{\geq\kappa} f(A) = f(A) $ if $ |f(A)| \geq \kappa $ and $*$ otherwise.
Now, $FX = P_{\geq \aleph_0}X + X$ if my cardinal arithmetic does not fail me.